# Do native speakers actually "feel" the difference between the following sentences?

Tags: questions, negation, quantifiers

> [A] *Haven’t they sold many tickets?*
>
> [B] *Haven’t they sold a lot of tickets?*

According to [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers), there's a difference in meaning here.

> When we use much and many in negative questions, we are usually
>   expecting that a large quantity of something isn’t there. When we use
>   a lot of and lots of in negative questions, we are usually expecting a
>   large quantity of something.

Is this distinction clear to native speakers? Do they actually use it and understand it the way it's described?

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to understand it myself.

Why does using *many/much* show that we expect there's a small quantity of something?

Why does using *a lot of* show that we expect a large quantity of something?

Comment: Hello, Katherine. First of all one has to look at the exclamatory sentence _"Haven’t they sold a lot of tickets!"_ This informs (when being read) one's take of the second sentence above. The first sentence can't be visualised this way. // However, immediate context will inform the reading to a greater degree.

Comment: Welcome to SE ELU. This site is for objective questions not those which are a matter of opinion. It is also primarily for native speakers. Therefore don’t ask whether people feel a difference, ask what the difference is. And in general ask on English Language Learners rather than here. See the Tour, which you never completed.

Comment: After reading the CED examples in situ, I think that they are confusing the exclamatory observation "Haven't they sold a lot of tickets. [I thought they'd sell quite a few, but not this many!]" with a true question. I'd say "Isn’t there much food left?" and "Isn’t there a lot of food left?" are paraphrases, while "Isn’t there a lot of food left!/." is the exclamatory observation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you are saying what I was thinking, but I’m not sure. Are you saying the second sentence is or can be exclamatory - equivalent to “what a lot ...”?   If so, I agree with you.  There can be a difference.  Sentence 1 expresses disbelief (ie surprise) at the idea that they have not sold many tickets (“can it really be the case that) they haven’t ...?”.

Comment: Yes. There is a difference. The dictionary is more or less correct here.  However, it depends on the state of the conversation prior to the question, which is somewhat *rhetorical* in nature.

Comment: @Tuffy On a re-re-read, perhaps I'm doing CED a disservice. There's a reading of [B], as I think Global implies, in the context: _["But I was hearing that the 'Purple Floyd' concert was looking like being a great success.] Haven’t they sold a lot of tickets [already]?"_ (ie **I'm looking for _confirmation_ that a lot have been sold.**) //  [A] is certainly expecting, or being quite prepared to be given,  confirmation that not many tickets have been sold. "[Why is the concert likely to be cancelled?] Haven’t they sold many tickets?" // Quite tricky! Good question.

Comment: As a native speaker, my *personal* intuition is that the first sentence is unnatural; the second is more normal. Even the statement *they have sold many tickets* would sound better—but still not as good as *they have sold a lot of tickets*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the feelings of native speakers are only likely to give individual subjective answers.

Answer (score 3):

The examples given in CED need more context to clarify the claims made in the dictionary.

There's a reading of [B], as I think Global implies, in the context:

> ["But I was hearing that the 'Purple Floyd' concert was looking like
>   being a great success.] Haven’t they [already] sold a lot of tickets?"
>   (ie I'm looking for confirmation that a lot have been sold)

that corresponds to 'When we use *a lot of* / *lots of* in negative questions, we are usually expecting there to be a large quantity of something, and soliciting confirmation' (From CED, amended).

Conversely, someone using [A] is certainly expecting, or being quite prepared to be given, confirmation that not many tickets have been sold:

> ["Why is the concert likely to be cancelled?] Haven’t they sold many
>   tickets?" (I'm expecting the answer "No").

.............................

Of course, the exclamatory sentence

> [C] "[Wow,] haven’t they sold a lot of tickets./!"

(there isn't one corresponding in form to [A]) must be distinguished, though it almost certainly influences some people's reading of [B]. But in speech, the intonation patterns used in [B] and [C] are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

*"Haven’t they sold many tickets?"* implies that ticket sales appear to be weak.

*"Haven’t they sold a lot of tickets?"* implies that ticket sales appear to be strong.

But a lot depends on the greater context.

Comment: I think your assessment of the "a lot" version is not well-founded. As a mere interrogative it could go either way.

Comment: @Robusto - As I said, a lot depends on the context.